# C# Regular Expressions on string

Tags: c#, regex

So I'm trying to find a string within a string, now I currently have this constructed in,

```
string str4;

var str5 = "   type: '");
foreach (string str6 in response.Split(new char[] { '\n' }))
{
    if (str6.StartsWith(str5))
    {
        str4 = str6.Replace(str5, "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("',", "");
        break;
    }
}
```

Which works as expected & will grab the text from

```
type: '
```

Example of this is

```
type: ' EXAMPLE ',
```

Ouput after loop

```
EXAMPLE
```

Now the issue is that occasionally the spaces at the start of '     type: ' vary, so sometimes it may be equal to the spaces I provided, and other times it may not..

I was trying to use Regex so I could do something such as,

```
string str5 = "Regex(*)type: '"
```

Now of course that's completely incorrect in terms of usage, but my example shows the use of * which would be equal to any possibilities, so therefore no matter on the number of spaces, I would still be able to extract the innertext from type.

Comment: Variable names like `str4`, `str5` or `str6` are good for R2-D2, not for humans. Choose speaking names like `result` (instead of `str4`), `searchPattern` (instead of `str5`), `line` (instead of `str6`).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks for your input, I'll take that into account upon my next question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we would simply add optional spaces before and after our desired outputs, e.g., `Example`, and we can start with this expression, for instance:

```
type:(\s+)?'(\s+)?(.+?)(\s+)?',
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jNmoP2/1/)

or:

```
type:(\s+)?'(\s+)?(.+?)(\s+)?'
```

if we might have types of `'`, we would expand our expression to:

```
type:(\s+)?['"](\s+)?(.+?)(\s+)?['"]
```

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"type:(\s+)?'(\s+)?(.+?)(\s+)?',";
        string input = @"type:' EXAMPLE ',
type: ' EXAMPLE ',
type:    '   EXAMPLE    ',
type:    '   Any other EXAMPLE we might have   ',";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Using Regex just for the sake of using Regex should be discouraged. It provides extra overhead and highly unreadable code.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto both answers will work, I miswrote my explination, the spaces are at the start of the string, so TrimStart() & TrimEnd() will work just as well.. Thank you all for your input though! Appreciate it from all 3 of you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Trim()`, `.TrimStart()` and `.TrimEnd()`. Using Regex looks like extra overhead which you don't really need.

Comment: "Now the issue is that occasionally the spaces at the start of ' type: ' vary, so sometimes it may be the equal to the spaces I provided, and other times it may not". This answer oversimplifies what's needed

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto not really. TrimStart: "Removes all leading occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String object."

It doesn't matter if there are 4 spaces or 400 spaces, it will remove them all.

Comment: ... and the input is `type: ' EXAMPLE '` so I'm not sure why you think calling just `TrimStart()`/`TrimEnd()` will work

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, one of us has clearly not understood what the OP has asked. I fail to understand why `' EXAMPLE '` cannot be trimmed to `'EXAMPLE'` with just a `.Trim()`

Comment: Well, you clearly didn't read the question. Input: `type: ' EXAMPLE ',`, output `EXAMPLE`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I read that. It's a simple Trim, Replace and Trim again.

Comment: This was simply my mistake, however Mark took the time to read full description and noticed I mentioned the spaces were at the start of the string, but from my example I didn't correctly add spacing.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a simple extraction task with very limited variation in inputs, you *can* do it with plain Regex:

```
var response = @"[{
   type: 'foo',
something: 'bar',
},
{
  type: 'baz',
  something: 'bat'
}]";
var types = Regex.Matches(response, @"\s*type\:\s*\'(.+)\'")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Single().Value);
```

But it *sounds like* you might be trying to write a parser for a programming or markup language. If so, I would highly recommend that you don't try to do that with Regex. Regular Expressions get really hairy the moment you start trying to handle things like escaped strings (`"type: 'I\'m a type: '"`).

If your input is in a standard format like JSON, use a parsing library for that format. If not, there are libraries like Sprache which make it easy to create powerful custom parsers.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are going to use Regex try out your regex strings here: https://regex101.com/

Second, If you can avoid RegEx, I would advise you to so. If a developer uses regex to solve a problem, now he has two problems. Regex can be tricky if you haven't worked with a lot. Having said that, here's another regex based solution. Also, there're usually several ways to construct a RegEx string.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] SampleInputList = new string[]
            {
                "type:EXAMPLE",
                " type: EXAMPLE ",
                "   type:  EXAMPLE  "
            };

            // The following is a non-capture group indicator: (?:)
            // non-capture groups are a good way to organize parts
            // of your regex string and can help you visualize the
            // parts that are just markers like 'type:' vs. the parts
            // that you want to actually manipulate in the code.
            Regex expression = new Regex(@"(?:\s*type\:\s*)([A-Za-z]*)");

            foreach (string Sample in SampleInputList)
            {
                MatchCollection matches = expression.Matches(Sample);
                if (matches.Count > 0)
                {
                    GroupCollection groups = matches[0].Groups;
                    if (groups.Count > 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(groups[1].Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```